# Bootstrap Tables Set Checkbox of specific rows marked as Checked

Tags: .net, .net-core, bootstrap-table, razor-pages

I am using Bootstrap Tables.  Documentation Located [Here](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/)

I am using Pagination on a large amount of dynamically generated data from a MySQL server.  I am using checkboxes at the beginning of the table, however I need a way to sample the hundreds of entries and then pre-checkmark a few of these entries based off existing data.

I have tried using `$("#storeTable").bootstrapTable('getData', false);` To be able to cycle through all of the entries and check them using a post table load method, however this only returns the 10 or so rows that are displayed in pagination.

Any help here on a fix or a strategy to accomplish this would be nice.  It would also be nice if after checking them I could get the checked ones to sort to the top.

[Picture of Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFcjF.png)

```
<div class="form-group">
                <div id="@ViewData["Title"]" class="table-responsive text-nowrap" style="white-space:normal; overflow-x:scroll">
                    <table id="storeTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width:100%" data-toggle="table" data-search="true" data-toolbar="#toolbar" data-pagination="true" data-side-pagination="client" data-show-pagination-switch="true" data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, ALL]" data-click-to-select="true" data-filter>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th data-sortable="true" data-checkbox="true">
                                </th>
                                <th data-field="cg" data-sortable="true">
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.dealeradminstore[0].cg)
                                </th>
                                <th data-field="sn" data-sortable="true">
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.dealeradminstore[0].serial_number)
                                </th>
                                <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.dealeradminstore[0].Name)
                                </th>
                                <th data-sortable="true">
                                    WebReports
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model.dealeradminstore)
                            {
                                <tr id="@test.NullRefExcl(item.serial_number.ToString())">
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>
                                        @test.NullRefExcl(item.cg.ToString())
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @test.NullRefExcl(item.serial_number.ToString())
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @test.NullRefExcl(item.Name)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @{string reportsCheck = "";
                                            if (test.NullRefExcl(item.base_xtags).Contains("RPT"))
                                            {
                                                reportsCheck = "Yes";
                                            }
                                            if (!test.NullRefExcl(item.base_xtags).Contains("RPT"))
                                            {
                                                reportsCheck = "No";
                                            }
                                        }
                                        @test.NullRefExcl(reportsCheck)
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the pagination function the table will only load the 10 rows of the current page.

When you would like to show the rows which fit to your parameters, you must ajust your MySql query. Which request the Data from the Database.